# Javascript - Overriding styles previously declared in another function

Tags: javascript, css, events, styles, overriding

Ok, this is my HTML

```
<div id="plus" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 303px;">
      <div id="plus-back"> </div>
      <div id="plus-ex"> X </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: the `#plus` element's inline styles was declared previuously by another script

And this is my JS

```
document.getElementById("plus").onclick = showNav 
document.getElementById("plus-ex").onclick = hideNav

function showNav(){
    this.style.width="200px"
    this.style.height="200px"
    document.getElementById("plus-ex").style.display="block"
}
function hideNav(){
    document.getElementById("plus").style.width="48px"
    document.getElementById("plus").style.height="48px"
}
```

Well.. this is what i have. The goal is simple, when you click `#plus`, this is expanded to show some content, and appears a "X" that is inside `#plus-ex`, and when you click that "X", `#plus` go back to the start (that is a div with 48px of height and width thanks to stylesheet). The problem with this, is that `hideNav()` is not doing a good work. When you click `#plus`, `showNav()` function is fired successfully, but after that, when you click the "X" and hideNav() is fired (successfully too), that should apply the initial style, but does anything. I have tested applying another CSS propieties like `background-color` and works OK, but not with `width` and `height`.

I think that the problem is that i can't override the styles applied by `showNav()`

What should i do?

Comment: maybe the problem is `.style.display="block"` ?

Comment: @muratgu No, i deleted `.style.display="block"` but the problem persist.

Comment: @Yavierre: `<div>` by default will shrink/wrap its height based on its content. I'm afraid you cannot set its height explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is when you click `X` the event is bubbling up to the `#plus` div.  You can prevent this by calling:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Update your code as follows and give it a try:

```
document.getElementById("plus").onclick = showNav 
document.getElementById("plus-ex").onclick = hideNav

function showNav(){
    this.style.width="200px"
    this.style.height="200px"
    document.getElementById("plus-ex").style.display="block" // Don't need this line as it's a block element i.e. already a div

    event.stopPropagation(); // add this line
}
function hideNav(){
    document.getElementById("plus").style.width="48px"
    document.getElementById("plus").style.height="48px"

    event.stopPropagation(); // add this line
}
```

Comment: THAT WORKS! i didn't know about "bubbling", and `event.stopPropagation()` have a bug in IE but i have found a solution. Thanks!